# What does とでも mean?

Tags: meaning, particle-でも

> [name]**とでも**呼んでくれたら嬉しい

What does とでも mean here? I know what と and でも mean separately but why are they used together here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key word here is 「[呼]{よ}ぶ」 = "to call (someone) by (a certain name)"

「[Name] + と + 呼ぶ」 = "to call (someone [name]) "  「と」 here is a quotative particle.

「[Name] + と + でも + 呼ぶ」 = "to call (someone [Name] or something)"

「でも」 means "~~ or something" here.

> 「[name]とでも呼んでくれたら[嬉]{うれ}しい」 = "I would be happy if you called me [name] or something."